# Where can I find source files for Google Navigation SDK for iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I would like to integrate Google Navigation SDK into my iOS app. I follow these instructions:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/navigation/ios-sdk/config

The documentation says "Unpack the source files that you received from Google". What does it mean? Should I contact Google Sales somehow? Are these source files available from some shared drive or similar?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`Navigation SDK` is currently available only to select customers. You need to contact [sales](https://cloud.google.com/contact-maps).

It is mentioned on the very top of the this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/navigation/ios-sdk/config).
[image]